# Question about affine subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $F$. Let $v_1$ and $v_2$ be two distinct elements of $V$. The line through $v_1$ and $v_2$ is the set $L \subset V$ given by $L = \{rv_1+sv_2 | r,s \in F, r+s=1\}$. Assume $X$ is a non-empty subset of $V$ that contains all lines through two distinct elements of $X$. Show that $X$ is a coset of some subspace of $V$.

It can be shown that $L$ can be generalized to a subspace. However I am not sure about the condition on $X$. It should be shown geometrically that $X$ consists of all lines parallel to $L$ to be a coset of it right?

Comment: What you are describing is a convex set. This statement does not look correct (For instance, the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not the translation of any line through the origin).

Comment: How would I show X is a coset of some subspace of V?

Comment: That's my point. You wouldn't be able to show $X$ is a coset, because it isn't.

Comment: would the question make sense if it were two distinct elements of V or L instead
couldn't X be a coset of some subspace of V that is not necessarily L.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is fine; the comments by Prahlad would apply only if both $r+s = 1$ and $r, s$ are *nonnegative* (as in the case $F = \mathbb{R}$). But that isn't one of the assumptions here.

If $X$ satisfies this condition, and $v \in X$ is any element (such $v$ exists since $X$ is assumed nonempty), then you should be able to show that the translate set

$$-v + X = \{-v + u: u \in X\}$$

is a vector subspace $W$ of $V$. You need to show $W$ is closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. Try scalar multiplication first: for $r \in F$, we have

$$r(-v + u) = -rv + r u = -v + ((1-r)v + r u)$$

(and therefore...). Then, for vector addition, observe that

$$\frac1{2}((-v + u) + (-v + w)) = -v + (\frac1{2}u + \frac1{2}w)$$

to conclude the left side belongs to $-v + X$; then combine this with closure under scalar multiplication in some way...

Once this is done, then $X = v + W$: this gives the coset representation.